# reapaint method not calling paint for canvas if canvas is not in container

Tags: java, canvas, awt

I am writing a 3 tier application for console of VM. In middle tier I am fetching console from server and putting it on canvas and returning it as image to client using AJAX. Now when the console is updated I am calling repaint method. But paint method is not getting called. I am assuming as it is not added to any Frame/Container the paint method is not getting called.

When I am directly calling paint() method then also it is not working.

How can I make sure paint is getting called through repaint method so that canvas gets updated without adding canvas to any container?

When I am adding same canvas to Frame then paint is getting called and everything works as expected.

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/). 2) Please don't forget to add a '?' to questions!  Some people do a search in the page for '?' and if none exists in the 'question' go directly to the next (actual) question in line.

Comment: *"..fetching console from server.."*  Is it an 'headless' server?

Comment: its rdp server(hyperv)

Comment: That does not answer my question.  Yes or no, is it headless?

Comment: Most drawing operations fail in a headless environment.

Comment: isn't there any method to force repaint to call paint method in headless environment?

Comment: Make it a non-headless environment.

Comment: so it means adding the canvas to fake container, which will not be used anywhere and setting the property java.awt.headless to false?

Comment: Try that.  I only know that if it is headless, it will fail.